# How can i put constants in a function and not make them global

Tags: javascript, function

How can i put constants in a function (fullpage, i guess) and not make them global. I think this is a bad practice. But I do not want to duplicate them in each event, I would like to indicate only once. I would like to know what can be done with this.

```js
// This constants
const tl = new TimelineMax({ delay: 0.5 });
const title = destination.item.querySelector("h1");

new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  navigation: true,


  afterLoad: function (destination) {
    // I do not want to repeat them here

    if (destination.index === 0) {
      tl.fromTo(title, 1, { y: "20", opacity: 0 }, { y: "0", opacity: 1 });
    }
  },


  onLeave: (destination) => {
    // And here

    tl.fromTo(title, 1, { y: "20", opacity: 0 }, { y: "0", opacity: 1 });


    if (destination.index === 1) {
      const chairs = document.querySelectorAll(".chair");
      const description = document.querySelector(".description");

      // Here i animate "chairs" and "description"
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the `title` is not really a constant, so what you need is simply a function.

```
{
const tl = new TimelineMax({delay: 0.5});
const title_of = x => x.item.querySelector("h1");

new fullpage('#fullpage', {

  //well why you use normal function here (I shortened it a little)
  afterLoad(destination) {
    const title = title_of(destination)
    //...
  },

  //and arrow function here?
  onLeave: (destination) => {
    const title = title_of(destination)
    //...
  }
})
```

---

** This block of answer doesn't really reflect OP's need, but since it answer the title, I'd keep it here. **

simply wrap them in a block. since `const` define a *block level* variable

```
{
   const tl = new TimelineMax({ delay: 0.5 });
   const title = destination.item.querySelector("h1");

   new fullpage('#fullpage', {...})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method really works. But `title` is taken from function parameters. 

```onLeave: function (destination) => {
    const title = destination.item.querySelector("h1"); 
}```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the code in an IIFE so they are scoped to that function.

```
(function () {
    const foo = 1; // Local to the function defined on the previous line

    // and accessible to any function defined here
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your code within a block as `const` and `let` are block-scoped [1]:

```
{
  const tl = new TimelineMax({ delay: 0.5 });
  const title = destination.item.querySelector("h1");

  new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    // you can use `tl` and `title` here`...
  })
}

// ...but not here
console.log(tl) //=> ReferenceError: tl is not defined
```

[1] https://wesbos.com/javascript-scoping/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method really works. But `title` is taken from function parameters.



``` lang-js
Leave: (origin, destination, direction) => {
const title = destination.item.querySelector("h1");
}
```